# how do I return a filtered list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not sure if my title is correct, but linq should pull the right experts in to help the title and answer the question.

If I have a list of People, how do I return a list of PeopleWrappers minus "Dave" and "Jane"?

query looks like this right now:

```
List<Person> People = CreatListofPersons();
People.Select(t => new PeopleWrapper(t)).ToArray();
```

Comment: does it matter if "Where" comes before "Select" or after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
People.Where( x => x.Name!="Dave" && x.Name!="Jane")
      .Select(t => new PeopleWrapper(t))
      .ToArray();
```

LINQ has a list of extension methods that allow you to filter or project (which you already to with `Select()`). In your case you can use [`Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to specify which elements you want to let pass, in your example all persons whose name is neither Dave nor Jane.

> does it matter if "Where" comes before
>   "Select" or after?

You typically want to filter *as soon as you can*, otherwise you will have to iterate and/or project over items you don't want to have anyway.

Conceptually though, yes, you can put there `where()` filter later **but** in your case you are dealing with a `PeopleWrapper` after you project with `Select()` - since the `Where()` extension method is using this data type as input its condition I don't think it would make much sense - you would filter people wrappers, not persons.

Answer (score 0):

```
return People.Where(p => p.Name != "Dave" && p.Name != "Jane");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Where to get just the elements that match a condition:

```
People.Where(p => p.name != "Dave" && p.name != "Jane" ).Select(t => new PeopleWrapper(t)).ToArray()
```